# Route with name "" not found

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

Here is my module.config.php

```
return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'subscription' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/subscription',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Subscription\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Account',
                    'action' => 'subscribe',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'process' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '[/:controller][/:action]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ), // end subscription
    ),
), // end router
'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Subscription\Controller\Account' => 'Subscription\Controller\AccountController',
     ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
    'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ),
),
```

);

I have used this code for all my modules, but in this specific module this doesn't work, and I have an error

> Route with name "" not found

I can't understand why is this happening, because this config works on my other modules.

Please Help!

Thank you!

Comment: You need to ask a question!

Comment: sorry, already solved it! it was my mistake! thank you by the way :)

Comment: What was the problem. The route type?